# ¿Porque me dice undefined al hacer log una variable?

Tags: cordova, ionic2

Saludos tengo una variable la cual declaro asi :public clickNotificacion:boolean=false;. Pero al dar clic debe cambiar de false a true y cuando hago el console.log(this.clickNotificacion). En el console.log muestra undefined.

```
public clickNotificacion:boolean=false;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){
LocalNotifications.on("click", function (notification) {
  console.info("Despues del click"+this.clickNotificacion);
  console.log(notification.id);
});
}
```

ionic info:
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.43
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.8
Node Version: v6.5.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Answer (score 1):

No uses on() y menos dentro del constructor. Simplemente crea la funcion fuera del constructor:

```
public clickNotificacion: boolean = false;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

changeNotification() {
    this.clickNotificacion = !this.clickNotificacion;
});
```

Y en el template le haces referencia a la misma:

```
<button ion-item (click)="changeNotification()">
  <ion-icon item-left name="notifications"></ion-icon>
  Notificaciones
</button>
```